# Clean out repository indexes on 16.04

Tags: repository, reset, cleanup

How do i clear out my repo indexes completely, start from scratch etc.
I have a lot of bad or old indexes that I'd like to clean up

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found to re
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/jupiter'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I do know how to remove repo's from the command line

Answer (score 3):

Simply edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for normal repositories. PPA entries you can find in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Simply edit with `sudo nano`.

Or you can use `banish404` which you can find in the official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install banish404 gksu
```

And starting it with:

```
gksudo banish404
```